# Make it possible for users to add reviews or quotes on a drupal node

Tags: drupal

I am looking for an easy way of giving a possibility to site users to add reviews or quotes on  a drupal node. The perfect example can be found on the goodreads.com website where users can add a quote or a review on a given book.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Users of this website are generally more inclined to help if you have made some strides towards a solution. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Most basic: Use the Comment module.

Answer (score 0):

Add additional fields to the Comments built into nodes.

You can also look into the Flag/Rate modules.